# Origin of 玉(たま) as a circular object

Tags: meaning, kanji, etymology

In Chinese, 玉 means jade or something beautiful/valuable. But in Japanese, it can mean a variety of other things such as a circular object, female entertainer, testicles etc. I'm curious as to when 玉{たま} started being used in Japanese to mean things other than the meanings that existed in Chinese. Sources from olden times using it in such a way would be awesome.

Comment: Do you mean to ask when the Chinese character 玉 began to be used for the Japanese word たま? I am not sure if there are many words where the character 玉 is pronounced ぎょく and is used in very different meanings from Chinese.

Comment: Yeah I mean たま primarily. I've edited my question. However, at least according to dictionaries, ぎょく is used in meanings that are quite different. See `６ 芸者のこと。` and `４ 取引所で、取引の対象となる株式や商品。` from 小学館(https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%8E%89)

Comment: I’ve never heard 玉 used in those senses. They must be jargon and metaphors for valuable things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appear to be two questions in your post.  :)

## Origin of the word たま ("jewel; small round thing")

This appears in some of the oldest documents written in Japanese, such as the [*Nihon Shoki*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihon_Shoki) of 720.  This is also reflected in Okinawan *tama* ("jewel; small round thing"), further indicating that this term is likely part of the core Proto-Japonic vocabulary.

Japanese references like [the *Kokugo Daijiten* (*KDJ*) entry here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%8E%89%E3%83%BB%E7%8F%A0%E3%83%BB%E7%90%83-2060412) suggest that 玉【たま】 ("jewel; small round thing") may be cognate with 魂【たましい】 ("soul, spirit"), possibly from a shared sense of "precious, mystical".  Any further derivation is hard to trace, due to the lack of any older textual evidence for the term.

Looking outside of Japonic for comparisons, I found that Ainu has a word *tama* meaning "ball; bead", as recorded [here on page 437](https://archive.org/details/ainuenglishjapan00batcuoft/page/436/mode/2up?view=theater) in the 1905 edition of John Batchelor's *Ainu-English-Japanese Dictionary*.  However, this seems like a borrowing from Japanese into Ainu: Ainu only seems to have one other term related to this, *tamane* ("to become a ball"), but that's clearly just noun *tama* ("ball") + verb [*ne*](https://archive.org/details/ainuenglishjapan00batcuoft/page/276/mode/2up?view=theater) ("to be, to become").

Looking to the Asian mainland, I did find Mongolian [тана](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0#Mongolian) (*tana*, "mother of pearl").  The meaning is roughly in the right general area, but there is that //n// ↔ //m// mismatch with Japonic.

Korean seems to have borrowed the word *tama* from Japanese, as [다마](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%8B%A4%EB%A7%88#Korean) (*dama*, "ball; marble; lightbulb").  The native Korean term for "marble; gem, jewel" is [구슬](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EA%B5%AC%EC%8A%AC#Korean) (*guseul*).  This Koreanic phonemic shape clearly has nothing in common with Japonic *tama*.  Rather, the [*Samguk Sagi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samguk_Sagi) records a Goguryeo place name **kos* ("jade; jewel") and a likely-related Baekje place name **kus* ("something precious"), possibly cognate with Japanese [奇【くす】し](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A5%87%E3%81%97#Japanese) ("mystical, strange, wonderful, precious") and [薬【くすり】](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%96%AC#Japanese) ("medicine", from the mystical effect these would have on the body).

## Use of the Chinese character 玉 to spell the native Japanese word たま

Written Japanese has used multiple kanji to spell *tama*.  [The *KDJ* entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%8E%89%E3%83%BB%E7%8F%A0%E3%83%BB%E7%90%83-2060412) lists three as the canonical accepted spellings, 玉・珠・球, as does [the *Daijisen* entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%8E%89-53197#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89).

Looking at the three 玉・珠・球, we can see that these all share the element 王, which is actually the older form of 玉 (as explained [here at Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%8E%89#Chinese)).  These have some semantic (meaning) overlap in Chinese as well:

- [玉](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%8E%89#Chinese): "jade; gem"
- [球](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%90%83#Chinese): "jade; ball"
- [珠](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%8F%A0#Chinese): "pearl; bead"

All of these refer to "something precious", and "something round".  This matches the core senses underlying usage in Japanese, as you note: *"a circular object, female entertainer, testicles"*.

As for why 玉 came to be used commonly in Japanese for the "small round thing" sense, I suspect it was a combination of this semantic overlap, combined with the simple fact that 玉 is a simpler character and easier to write than the alternatives.

#### Update

The *KDJ* is pretty good about listing the oldest known citations for each individual sense of a word.  That said, their focus is on the meanings more than the spellings, so I'm not sure if their [entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%8E%89%E3%83%BB%E7%8F%A0%E3%83%BB%E7%90%83-2060412) includes the oldest known instances of each spelling.

Be that as it may, a quick perusal there shows that the 玉 spelling in their quotes first appears from 1566 in reference to "testicles":

- [1]③(チ) 男子の生殖器。「きんたま」の略。
  ※全九集（1566頃）五「へのこはれやぶれ黄水いづ、**玉**もかたくはれ痛み」

The next-oldest is from 1622 in reference to "pellet, bullet":

- [1]③(ロ) (「弾・弾丸」とも書く) (初期のものは丸くなっていたところから) 弾丸。
  ※信長記（1622）三「是は杉谷善住坊といひし鉄炮の上手、〈略〉二つ**玉**(タマ)をもって纔十間ばかりにてうちはづし申事も」

That said, I've noticed in the past that sometimes the quotes in the *KDJ* use normalized or simplified spellings, where the actual source documents used different characters.  So it's possible that different editions of the source documents might have used 玉 where the citations in the *KDJ* entry use just hiragana たま.

Comment: Good point about really having two questions. I suppose the thing I'm most interested in is `when` did 玉 first (or commonly) start being used to write tama.

Comment: @Ringil, I've added an "Update" section to address your question about dating the spelling.